# Stylus. How to use variable in the name of hashes

Tags: variables, hash, stylus

as a substitute variable in the name of hashes

```
some_hashes = {
    some_hashes_value: some_variable
}

some_mixin(some_argument, some_argument_2)
    margin: {some_argument}[some_hashes_value] + some_argument_2 // false
    margin: {some_argument}.some_hashes_value + some_argument_2 // false


.foo
    some_mixin 10
```

expected ":", got "}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [lookup](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/bifs.html#lookupname) bif in this case.

Comment: `foo = {
 ro: 10px
}

some_argument = foo
some_argument2 = ro

.foo
 margin: lookup(some_argument + '.' + 'ro') // false. cannot perform {"ro":"(10px)"} + '.'
 margin: define(some_argument + '.' , 'ro') // false. cannot perform {"ro":"(10px)"} + '.'
 margin: operate( '.', some_argument, some_argument2) // work
`
Thanks for help ! It helped me